# find duplicate filenames and append them to hash of arrays

Tags: perl

Perl question: I have a colon separated file containing paths that I'm using. I just split using a regex, like this:

```
my %unique_import_hash;

while (my $line = <$log_fh>) {
    my ($log_type, $log_import_filename, $log_object_filename) 
        = split /:/, line;

    $log_type =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; # trim whitespace
    $log_import_filename =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; # trim whitespace
    $log_object_filename =~ s/^\s+|\s+$//g; # trim whitespace
}
```

The exact file format is:

```
type : source-filename : import-filename
```

What I want is an index file that contains the last pushed `$log_object_filename` for each unique key `$log_import_filename`, so, what I'm going to do in English/Perl pseudo-code is push the `$log_object_filename` onto an array indexed by the hash `%unique_import_hash`. Then, I want to iterate over the keys and pop the array referred by `%unique_import_hash` and store it in an array of scalars.

**My specific question is**: *what is the syntax for appending to an array that is the value of a hash?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
my %unique_import_hash;

my $log_filename = "file.log";
open(my $log_fh, "<" . $log_filename);

while (my $line = <$log_fh>) {
    $line =~ s/ *: */:/g;
    (my $log_type, my $log_import_filename, my $log_object_filename) = split /:/, $line;
    push (@{$unique_import_hash{$log_import_filename}}, $log_object_filename);
}
```

Seek the wisdom of the [Perl monks](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1977).

Comment: ...what's the reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [push](http://p3rl.org/push), but you have to dereference the array referenced by the hash value:

```
push @{ $hash{$key} }, $filename;
```

See [perlref](http://p3rl.org/perlref) for details.

Answer (score 4):

If you only care about the *last* value for each key, you're over-thinking the problem. No need to fool around with arrays when a simple assignment will overwrite the previous value:

```
while (my $line = <$log_fh>) {
    # ...
    $unique_import_hash{$log_import_filename} = $log_object_filename;
}
```

Comment: My thought exactly. I was however afraid of not knowing the whole problem: since he asked a *specific* question, he may have had some other use for it.

Comment: @simlev: Indeed. Moreover the question in the subject line is very different from tye question in the post.

Comment: I'm writing my own version of a git-like versioned file system with the intent of using it in a game. Game engines seem to almost universally suck wrt to filesystems. I want an incremental build based on patches. I feel like having access to previous file versions is really useful for doing A/B testing and seeing differences between versions of content and the like. Right now, I use a log that contains all versions of all files imported. Then I used the answer's code to filter out all but the last entry foreach unique import. Thanks guys.